# insert with many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

i have 2 object: user, group that have a relationship many to many
i want create a user and associate some groups to it.
How can i do it?

thanks

I've tried with this. but it's wrong:

```
user = new User();
List<int> gruppi = new List<int>() {1,2};
utente.Group =db.Group.Where(p => gruppi.Contains(p.GruppoID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
utente.Group.AddRange(db.Group.Where(p => gruppi.Contains(p.GruppoID))
```